# Inconsistency when plotting communities grouping

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I have a problem while plotting the communities. Please consider the following MWE

```
library(igraph)

m <- matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,
              1,0,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,1,0,
              4,1,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,1,
              0,0,0,0,0,0),nrow=6,ncol=6)

g <- graph.adjacency(m)
memb <- membership(edge.betweenness.community(g))
memb
# [1] 1 1 2 1 2 2
```

I then expect to see two communities in the plot when doing

```
plot(g, mark.groups=list(memb), edge.width=0.5, edge.arrow.width=0.2)
```

But actually I get only one community

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Isn't it two communities? (1,2,4) and (3,5,6)

Comment: No, only 1 and 2 are grouped... Sorry the picture is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you are using the `mark.groups` argument wrong. Try

```
plot(g, 
     mark.groups=lapply(unique(memb), function(n) which(memb==n)), 
     edge.width=0.5, 
     edge.arrow.width=0.2)
```

Comment: While this works, it is not the best practice. It is better to keep the `communities` object and use its builtin operations.

Answer (score 4):

You can plot the result of the community structure detection, the `communities` object, instead of plotting the graph. See the example in `?plot.communities`.

```
ebc <- edge.betweenness.community(g)
plot(ebc, g)
```

[image: plot]